# Service stops after I exit my application

Tags: android, service

I am working on a music player app and it runs as a remote service. When I press back button to exit, the service stops. Why is this happening?

It also shows the following logcat message

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return `START_STICKY` from the service's `onStartCommand`. Check the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)